# Run service from svc service on boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, services

I want to run svc service (daemontools/supervise) on system boot (without logging in).

The service is running fine if I manually run commands (using root):

- /usr/bin/svscan /services/ &(to start supervise)
- /usr/bin/svc -u /services/demoservice  (to start demoservice)

But I want to run these on system boot. I created entries in /etc/rc.local.
first command starts supervise on boot but second command is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`svscan` takes a non-zero amount of time to start up the `supervise`s, and they in turn take a non-zero amount of time to present the control/status API for the services that `svc`then uses.  You cannot expect `svc -u`, run in parallel whilst this is happening, to work.  **But** you don't need to run `svc -u` at bootstrap *in the first place*, to autostart something that is in `/services` and not configured as down.

You don't need to use the old `rc.local` when Gerrit Pape has made the daemontools-run package.  And in any case the command to run in the old `rc.local` way of doing things is `svscanboot`.  **However**, you are using Ubuntu Linux, and have had *no need* of the old `rc.local` way of doing things *for the past ten years*.

On Ubuntu 15, run svscan under systemd with a path unit and a service unit.  On Ubuntu 14, run svscan under upstart with a job file.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014-09-23). [*Where to put daemontools startup in systemd Jessie?*](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/09/msg01715.html).  debian-user.
- Jim Carroll (2006). [*DaemontoolsUpstartConfig*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DaemontoolsUpstartConfig).  Ubuntu wiki.
- Matt Pulver (2008-02-15). [*djb daemontools with Ubuntu’s upstart*](http://eigenjoy.com/2008/02/15/djb-daemontools-with-ubuntus-upstart/).  eigenjoy.
- Gerrit Pape.  [*Debian daemontools*](http://smarden.org/pape/Debian/daemontools.html).  Debian packages.
- [daemontools-run](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/daemontools-run).  Ubuntu 14.04 packages.
- Daniel J. Bernstein.  [*The `svscanboot` program*](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svscanboot.html).  daemontools.
- Bruce Guenter.  [*`svscanboot`*](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/svscanboot.8.html).  daemontools-encore.